# How to eliminate crosstalk in my headset

Tags: microphone, headset

The mic in my headset picksup sound that comes from the headset speakers. I checked if stereo mix is on but no its off. Its an issue with headset itself. I desperately need a fix for it.

Comment: The keyword you need to google for is "echo cancellation". Many applications that allow a headset for communication (Zoom etc.) have this already built in.

Comment: I tried echo cancellation software but the sound coming to the mic is so intense even the software can't fully eliminate it.

Comment: Another option is that somehow loopback in your audio codec is enabled. Test by using a different headset, and measure if the echo has the same amplitude.

Comment: I found something interesting. If I reduce the volume from my pc settings the echo will reduce. but if i reduce the volume using my headset volume control the echo will be the same.

Comment: The it looks like you have an enabled loopback somewhere.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: Under Linux, you can dump the codec settings from `/proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`, assuming it's an Intel HDA codec. Inspect them, figure out where the loopback is, use `amixer` or the hda utilities to change. Under Windows, I have no idea, nor for MacOS.

Comment: I kinda have a feeling its an issue inside the headset you know. and also I am using a USB sound card.